# How to create a group from CSV file?

Tags: import, data-import

I have a CSV file with email addresses. Part of these addresses are in CiviCRM.

How can I create a CiviCRM group that includes contacts with emails matching those in CSV file?

Comment: In your group, do you want only existing CiviCRM contacts who are also in your CSV - or all the addresses in your CSV?

Answer (score 1):

(EDIT - read Lars' suggestion first)

Seems clumsy but this might work.

Run the import with SKIP and at the final step of the import there is an option to either add the contacts to a New Group (A) for the same.

This should give you a group of those who did not exist in db before import

Then re-run the import without SKIP and create new group (B) so that should give you all the list.

then use Custom Search called Include/Exclude and

Comment: Could also simplify a little bit by using IGNORE and then search by date added in an advanced search, so you'd only have to do one import.

Comment: If this is something ongoing, maybe a Google Sheet with an Apps Script that calls the API?

Comment: good idea about running that single import.